# Why doesnt it print

Tags: python, variables

I dont understand why it doesnt print the sentence. I have tried everything i can think off but im new to python is there something im missing?

```
def main():
    print("1 = USD 2= GB pounds 3 = Japanse Yen")
valuta = input(" Welke valuta wilt u in wisselen voor de euro (graag het getal geven) ")
if  __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: works in google collab. What are your expectations ?

Comment: Which sentence? You hve two strings. Since `valuta` is not indented, it is not part of `main` and is executed before main is even called. It will print " Welke valuta wilt..." and then wait for you to enter data _before_ calling `main` and its print.

Comment: @ScottHunter as the code is written, it works as expected nothing more. That's why I'm asking for the author to tell us about his expactions

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your code to:

```
def main():
    print("1 = USD 2= GB pounds 3 = Japanse Yen")
    valuta = input(" Welke valuta wilt u in wisselen voor de euro (graag het getal geven) ")
    print(valuta)

if  __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```